# Reordering the elements of a list so consecutive elements succeed one another?

Tags: algorithm, list, sorting, data-structures

Given a list of items l of size n, and given the predicate `succeeds(i1,i2)` that returns true if `i2` succeeds `i1`, what is the best algorithm to rearrange the elements of l such that for all items i in l, `succeeds(i,i.next)` returns true?

Comment: Is this any different to a standard sort? For example `std::list<T>::sort` using succeeds as a predicate?

Comment: Does your `succeeds` function guarantee that such an ordering exists ? What should be the output if there's no such ordering ? What if there is more than one ?

Comment: @AndrewWalker: This only works if `succeeds` models a strict weak ordering.

Comment: Is there a limitation on the number of elements that can succeed each element? [for a certain `i`, can two different elements succeed `i`?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If only one element can succeed each element**, then this problem is solveable in quadric time.

It is actually imitating creating a linked list from the data and returning it as an array. The bottleneck is finding for each element - which element is following it.

Pseudo-code:

```
specialSort(array,n)
   create an array a of size n
   for each i from 0 to n:
      find j such that succeeds(array[i],array[j]) == true //this may require linear search, so it is O(n)
      if there is such j:
          a[i] = j
      else:
          a[i] = -1
   end for
   find i such that for any j: a[j] != i
   create empty result array of size n
   j = 0;
   while (i != -1):
      result[j++] = array[i]
      i = a[i]
   end while
   return result
```

If there are no limitations on the number of elements that can succeed each element, then the answer @templatrtypedef gave you is correct, and your problem is equivalent to finding a hamiltonian path.

**EDIT: The problem is solveable for any well ordered relation**:

Note that if there can be more then one successor for each element, but the relation `succeed()` is well ordered [no "loops"], then you can build a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) from this problem [each element is a vertex, and there is an edge for every pair such that `succeed(a,b) == true`], use a [topological orderring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ordering) - and return it.

This is also quadric time, since again - the bottle neck is finding the edges.

Answer (score 4):

If there are no restrictions on what the succeeds relation can be (that is, it doesn't have to be transitive, reflexive, symmetric, etc.), then I think this problem is NP-hard by a reduction from the NP-hard **[Hamiltonian path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem)**.  The reduction is actually pretty simple: given a graph G, create an array of the nodes in the graph with the succeeds relationship such that v succeeds u iff there is an edge from u to v in the original graph.  With this setup, finding a way to order the array elements (nodes) by the succeeds relationship (edges connecting them) is equivalent to finding a Hamiltonian path in the original graph, since each node is visited exactly once.  Consequently, you are unlikely to find an efficient algorithm for this unless P = NP.

Sorry for the negative result, and hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting! However, I believe the reduction does not hold if you add a constraint, for each `i`: `|{j : succeeds(i,j) = true }| == 1` [or in other words, only one element succeeds each element], which *might* be what the OP is really after [concidering the fact that this task is homework]. In this case [with the constraint] a simple BFS/DFS finds the desired orderring.